# how to name a file from array index?

Tags: powershell

I have an array where I want to put the names of the files so when I call pester and publish the results of my tests, I get each test with their corresponding name

so far I have this:

```
  $file = "D:\ParametrosExcel.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count
     [System.Collections.ArrayList]$data = @(

    )
for ($row = 3; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {   # salta header
    $params = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$nameTests=@()
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    #Si la celda es igual a nulo, no se agrega al array de parametros
        if ($sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value()-ne $null){
         [System.Collections.ArrayList]$params += $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value()


        }
    }
    # si el parametro en la posición uno igual a 1 procede si no se brinca a la linea siguiente
    if ($params[0] -ne 0) {
        # muestra output

        $params.Remove($params[0])
          $nombrePrueba=$params[0]
         Write-Host "NOMBRE DE ESCENARIO" $nombrePrueba
         $nameTests.Add($nombrePrueba)

        $params.Remove($params[0])
        #Write-Output "Resultado1"  -f ($params -join '; ').TrimEnd(", ")

        #Write-Output "Resultado2"  -f ($params -join '; ').TrimEnd(", ")
       'Parametros: {0}' -f ($params -join ' ').TrimEnd(", ")

    $data.Add($params)

    }
}



$objExcel.Quit()
# cierra elementos usados
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)    | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$contador=0
foreach ($parametro in $data )
{

 $nombre= $nameTests[$contador]


Invoke-Pester -Script @{Path = 'C:\Turing\Tests\Azure.ps1'; Parameters = @{parameter=$parametro}} -OutputFile "C:\Turing\Test Results\'$nombre'.xml" -OutputFormat "NUnitXML"
$contador+=1

}
```

I'm sorry it is commented on spanish, but here

```
Write-Host "NOMBRE DE ESCENARIO" $nombrePrueba
             $nameTests.Add($nombrePrueba)
```

it's where I get the name I want and I add it to an array list and it adds it two times but when I print 
it like this

```
$nameTest[0]
$nameTest[1]
```

I get only one, but, the index zero changes from this "prueba1" to "prueba3", I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Thank you for the help

and the file it gets the name .xml only, I have tried to put it like this '$filename'.xml and nothing, and I know it just misses some ps trick haha but im a newbie in powershell, I hope someone can help me please, thank you very much for your kind help
Greetings!

Comment: what are the variables "$nameTests" and "$contador"? it sounds like they are empty.

Comment: Its an arraylist , and I made a write host to print the value and it shows the value I want :(

Comment: if you don't provide the full script (functional complete) it's hard to help. but you said `$nameTests[$contador]` works with write-host? what if you set `$filename` to this value and write-host it?

Comment: Remove the `| Out-String` and see if it works.  Also, does `$nameTests[$contador]` contain the base file name without extension?  Or the `.xml` is supposed to be a double extension for an existing file name?  So that `$filename` contains the _complete_ file name, you might instead do `$filename= "$($nameTests[$contador]).xml"` and `-OutputFile "C:\Turing\Test Results\$filename"`.

Comment: I updated my code, thanks for your responses, I don't know why but the values of the array get lost once I want to use them, I don't even have the index zero when I want to use it, and no, the file name only has the the name, not the xml extension so it only has it once

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to get the error, it was a missing space in here

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$nameTests=@()
```

so it turned out to be

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$nameTests = @()
```

so that was it, with that it worked without problems

thank you for all the help :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The spaces around the assignment operator are not significant, so both lines of code produce the same result.  What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: That's What I tought but Thats all I did and it worked, how can I know the ps versión?

Comment: That's stored in the `$PSVersionTable` variable.

Comment: this is the version that I have 5.1.18362.145

Answer (score 0):

As @BACON mentioned, the spacing is indeed irrelevant. Checking your current code snippet, I see three problems:

1. Formerly, you used `$variable=@()` to instantiate an empty, fixed
   array. On such arrays, you cannot use the `Add()` function to add
   elements. You have to use the expensive `+=` operator to create a
   new array that will additionally contain the new element. To solve
   this problem, you casted the raw array to an ArrayList, which can
   use the Add() function indeed. I think THAT solved your problem, and
   not your spacing.
2. You mention:

   > I get only one, but, the index zero changes from this "prueba1" to "prueba3", I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

   This is because you use `$params.Remove($params[0])` twice inside your if statement. So you process one element and skip its succeeding element in each iteration.
3. As long as your first problem was not solved, of course your output
   did not work. Now, you should remove the extra quotings `'` in
   `"C:\Turing\Test Results\'$nombre'.xml"` as I assume that you do not
   want to have this quoting inside your filename.

Comment: If you are suggesting that I had this $variable=@() and I solved with this System.Collections.ArrayList]$nameTests then no, i always had system. Collection etc etc I only added the space it is as bizarre to me, as it is to you